# Why does solution turn yellow at higher temperatures in potassium iodate-sodium metabisulfite variation?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

When I did the potassium iodide-sodium thiosulfate experiment, the reaction mixture did not turn yellow at higher temperatures. For example, it was blue-black at 50 degrees celsius, however, for iodate variation, it turned yellow at higher temperatures, like 50 degree. I do not understand why this happens.

According to what I understand starch must decompose, however, why doesn't it happen for iodide-thiosulfate?

To clarify the doubts

This is iodine clock reaction and both of them are variations of this experiment. Firstly, diluted potassium iodide reacts with acidified sodium thiosulfate with starch (starch acts as an indicator).  Solution turns blue-black when reaction is complete. For the iodate variation, diluted potassium iodate reacts with acidifed sodium metabisulfate with starch (which acts as an indicator). And, I am trying to understand why it turns yellow instead of blue-black for the iodate variation at higher temperatures?

Comment: Please give us more information. What is this potassium iodide-sodium thiosulfate experiment ? Iodide should not react with thiosulfate. What is the composition of the reaction mixture ? What do you mean when stating that "starch must decompose" ? Is there starch in this mixture ? Any other component ?  Why do you say that there is a "iodate variation" ? Iodate variation ? So it is not an experiment iodide + thiosulfate as informed in the first sentence.  It is a mixture of four instead of two components : iodide + iodate + starch + thiosulfate ? Is the mixture acidic or basic ? Explain !

Comment: @Maurice There is no space before question, or exclamation, mark... BTW why should OP explain every tidbit if [iodine clock reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine_clock_reaction) is well known?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/181480/why-does-iodate-and-acidified-metabisulfite-solution-turn-yellow-instead-of-blue, and one should be deleted.

Comment: Hello Maurice! Both of them are separate experiments. I have edited the question and I hope that it is more clear now :)