# Why does iodate and acidified metabisulfite solution turn yellow instead of blue at high temperatures (above 50)

Tags: kinetics

We are doing a kinetics investigation at school where we are trying to find the activation energy of the reaction between potassium iodate and sodium metabisulfite. Solution A contains 2g of potassium iodate per dm^3 of water and solution B, which is acidified, contains 0.25g of sodium metabisulfite per dm^3 of water and some starch. Solution A was diluted by five times and the ration used in the experiment was 6cm^3 solution A, 4cm^3 solution B and 10cm^3 water. At room temperature, when A and B were mixed, the solution turned blue which is what is to be expected, however, at temperatures greater than 40 degrees celsius, the solution turns yellow. Is there an explanation as to why this is?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/181473/why-does-solution-turn-yellow-at-higher-temperatures-in-potassium-iodate-sodium

Answer (score 0):

Iodine in water, as you've noticed, is yellowish to brown, depending on concentration. Starch contains [amylose, which combines with iodine to make a blue-colored colloid](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Biological_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Biological_Chemistry)/Carbohydrates/Case_Studies/Starch_and_Iodine).

You might simplify the experiment:

- Start with a solution of "metallic" iodine in water, which needs some iodide (e.g., $\ce{KI}$) to form the brown [complex triiodide ion](https://www.britannica.com/science/iodine/Physical-and-chemical-properties), i.e., [Lugol's iodine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lugol%27s_iodine) solution.
- Add some of the starch suspension to get the blue amylose-iodine complex.
- Heat it to 40°C and see if the blue color reverts to yellow-brown.
- *Allow it to cool to room temperature* to see if the blue color returns, and if it is *the same shade* as when the experiment started.

Does the color return?

Here are two hypotheses:

- The iodine is driven out of the amylose by heating.
- The amylose is destroyed by heating.

What do the results of the experiment show?